# How to inject a controller class in another controller? how can i achive the method with helloworld() with "test/controller1/hello"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller

how can i achive the method with helloworld()  with "test/controller1/hello"???

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public class Controller1 {
        
        @Autowired
        private Controller2 controller2;
        
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/controller2")
        
        public Controller2 getHelloController() {
            System.out.println("hello tv controller");
           return controller2;
    }


@RestController()
public class Controller2 {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello bill inquiry";
    }
}
```

this is because i have to manage a lot of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor the code. Extract what is common between the two controllers into a separate class, then call that from either controller.

Comment: controller1 should behave like a parent, there will be several methods to call different child controllers.